# Read numeric data with the right format from Google Sheets API

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

I want to read numeric cells in a Google Sheet with Python and the Google API.
In the Google Sheet, for the decimal values, we use a comma as a decimal separator.
I don't want to change the format and when I read the data the result just ignores the comma.
Example : For a value of 0,8, I get 8 as a result.

Here's my code :

```py
sheet = google_sheets_connection() # API connection 
sheet = sheet.worksheet(sheet_name)
data = sheet.get_all_records()  
print(data)
```

Input :

```
0,8
6,3
```

Expected output :

```
0.8
6.3
```

Current output :

```
8
63
```

I don't find anything on the Google documentation to format the reading and read commas as decimal separator.
Do you guys have a solution for this ?

Comment: Is the data in the cell stored as a float or is it a formatted integer?

Comment: @WilliamPearsall the data in the cell is stored as a number, I suppose it means float for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using gspread version 4.0.1.  The input is

[image]

with Automatic format.

See the [documentation for `get_all_records()`](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_records)

```
sheet = google_sheets_connection() # API connection 
sheet = sheet.worksheet(sheet_name)
data = sheet.get_all_records(numericise_ignore=['all'])  
print(data)
```

The output is

```
[{'0,8': '6,3'}]
```